# will and would usage

Tags: modal-verbs, will-would

> Do you think he will come?

---

or

> Do you think  he would come?

---

Which is the correct form? If both are correct, What is the difference in their meaning? I have seen similar questions, but the are not in interrogative form. As I am a new learner, I just wanted to learn clearly in various forms

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct usage of will and would](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/54580/correct-usage-of-will-and-would)

Comment: @Jdrupal yes , But could you please give an imaginary scenario, where the second sentence with would can be used

Answer (score 0):

"Would" can be the past-tense of "will", but when it is used about a future event in this way, it is for hypothetical situations or conjecture.

> Do you think that he will come?

This would be appropriate in situations where you *are* waiting for somebody, perhaps because you have invited them to attend something, and you were asking someone for their opinion on whether the person *will*, or *will not* come. Although their answer might be partly conjecture, it is an assessment of the invitee's response to a tangible invitation.

It is common to speak about hypothetical situations as if they were in the past, using verbs in the past tense (eg "Do you think he *would* come if I *asked* him?")

> Do you think he *would* come?

This would be appropriate if you were asking someone's opinion on a *hypothetical* situation - for example, if you were considering inviting someone to attend and event (but had not yet invited them). You are asking if the person would hypothetically attend *if* you invited them.